# How do I deal with very long lines in text (500+ characters)?

Tags: cursor-movement, large-documents

For some text formats, line breaks matter.

For example, I often use Vim to write MediaWiki documents, where you can't just put a linebreak anywhere (unlike Markdown). So I'm forced to write lines with a lot of characters.

This can lead to long (200+ chars) or even *very* long (1000+ chars) lines. I find this very awkward to use in Vim. One example is if I want to edit something in the middle of the 1000 character-line, I need to move my cursor 500 times.

This can be made a bit faster with `w` or `/`, but it's still awkward.

Are there better ways to deal with this? Better movement keys? Some sort of "fake wrapping" (text behaves as if `tw=80`, but no `\n` in the file), or something else?

Comment: You may also want to also [set display=lastline](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/102/show-partially-hidden-wrapped-lines) to avoid blank @ lines at the end of the screen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `g` series of commands to move to the boundaries of the visible screen area.  For example, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> moves to the right edge of the screen (which is not necessarily the end of the line).  <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> moves the cursor down one line *as it appears on your screen* (which is not necessarily one logical line down).

Perhaps you could rebind the arrow keys:

```
nnoremap <Up> gk
nnoremap <Down> gj
```

Or some people also directly rebind <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd>:

```
nnoremap k gk
nnoremap j gj
```

For insert mode, you could use:

```
inoremap <C-k> <C-o>gk
inoremap <C-j> <C-o>gj
```

Or:

```
inoremap <Up> <C-o>gk
inoremap <Down> <C-o>gj
```

---

In addition, if you use `:set wrap`, Vim will wrap the lines, so you can see all of the line. You can also use `set showbreak=+` to show a `+` to indicate that Vim is doing wrapping.

---

To jump to specific column positions, you can use the <kbd>|</kbd> command. For example, <kbd>200|</kbd> will go to column position 200.

Comment: ... and `g5j` to jump 5 down, as usual.

Comment: @yo' I think you mean `5gj`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Strange; with most commands it doesn't matter in which order you give the prefixes and the numbers, as long as the command itself is last. Here it does not :-/

Comment: @yo', well, in `g5j`, `g5` is seen first, which just jumps to the next `5` before you apply the `j`. That's why it can't do what `5gj` does.

Comment: The `nnoremap` commands function for Normal mode, but for Insert mode the `inoremap` commands do not. Any clue why?

Comment: @200-success: Isn't "set showsbreak=+" supposed to be "set showbreak=+"?

Comment: Indeed; I edited the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

When I'm dealing with very long lines, the biggest pain point has to do with differing line lengths. That is, moving up or down near the ends of the lines scrolls the window very far left or right.

This can be avoided by setting `virtualedit=all`, which allows you to move the cursor into the space long after the line endings.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has support for soft wrapping, just `set wrap` to enable it and it will wrap long lines going beyond the visible screen. You can use `gj` & `gk` to move up/down respectively over such wrapped lines.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can use <kbd>g</kbd> + something to move around.
However, when you have extremely long lines, pressing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> multiple times to move downward is not ergonomic. I have the following in my `.vimrc` to make that much easier:

```
vmap <D-j> gj
vmap <D-k> gk
vmap <D-4> g$
vmap <D-6> g^
vmap <D-0> g^
nmap <D-j> gj
nmap <D-k> gk
nmap <D-4> g$
nmap <D-6> g^
nmap <D-0> g^
```

On a Mac, this allows me to use j, k, $, 0 and ^ on display lines by holding down the command key. On other systems, instead of `D` you could try `M` or `A` for Alt, or `C` for Control.