# Show partially hidden wrapped lines

Tags: wrapping

I have turned on line wrapping with `set wrap linebreak nolist` in my .vimrc. However, this has the annoying behavior that lines not *completely* visible on the screen are hidden outright and replaced with @ signs:

[image]

How can I make these lines show up even though they are partially hidden?

Comment: My web service log file has a line that's 98518 characters wide. When wrapped it fills more than 1 screen. How can I scroll it smoothly in vim? Using navigation keys like $ and w isn't quite working, is there another key that jumps say 1000 characters at a time?

Comment: @ropata You could use something like `nnoremap H 1000h` and `nnoremap L 1000l` in your `.vimrc` to make `H` move left 1000 characters and similar for `L`, or you could wrap the line (`gww`) within Vim. But that's a different question, which you should [ask as a separate question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use:

```
:set display+=lastline
```

From [`:help 'display'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27display%27):

```
lastline        When included, as much as possible of the last line
                in a window will be displayed.  When not included, a
                last line that doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.
```

Comment: `:help 'display'` is more accurate.