# How can I show all of a long line, even if it wraps off the bottom of the screen?

Tags: wrapping

If I have a really long line, vim truncates it with `set nowrap`. If I `set wrap`, I can see all of the text, unless (after wrapping) it is too long to show all of it on the screen. For example, if the second line of my file is very long, none of it is shown at all. Instead, vim shows `@` on each line.

```
text on line 1
@
@
@
@
@
@
@
<status line>
```

While using `set wrap`, s there a way to get vim to show what it can of this long line, even if it wraps off the bottom of the window?

Comment: `:set display+=lastline` see duplicate question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/102/1841

Comment: Thanks @statox. I did search thoroughly, but obviously had some trouble knowing what to search for.

Comment: I can't blame you: we all have created a duplicate one day ;-)