# How to navigate long lines like separate lines?

Tags: cursor, wrapping, navigation

When I have a very long line in vim it will be shown on the screen as multiple lines, like this:

```
line no. | content                                           |
100      | this is a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo | 
         | ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo | 
         | ooooooong line!                                   |
101      | this is the next line                             |
```

when I type `k` on line 101 I will jump to the first line of line 100 (which is very counter-intuitive for me), is there a way that I could type 3 `k`s from line 101 to navigate the line 100?

Comment: Have you tried `gj` and `gk`?

Comment: I was pretty sure we have a duplicate for this one but I can't find an exact duplicate. [This question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/88/1841) is at least very related (and has the same content as Maxim's answer)

Comment: @statox I had the same feeling but, while `gj` and `gk` appear in a lot of answers, I also couldn't find a question closer than the one you linked.

Comment: @BLayer I guess we'll keep this one and use it for a future duplicate then :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `gj` and `gk` commands to move the cursor to the character in the next or previous *display* lines, even when lines wrap.

See [`:help gj`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gj) and [`:help gk`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gk) for details.

If you would like to navigate those display lines using `j` and `k`, you can remap them in your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

Beware that these remappings have side effects, for instance commands such as `dj` will behave differently even on lines that are not wrapped, since `gj` is not a linewise motion while `j` is. (The original `dj` will delete two lines, while the modified one won't.)

Comment: This answer has the right ketstrokes... But remapping is quite overkill. Maybe start the answer by simply stating you can use `gj` and `gk` to navigate long lines would be best. Follow that with a suggestion to map them if you find that useful, but don't lead with that. Would you please edit the answer to rephrase it that way? (Also, adding links to [`:help gk`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gk) and `:help gj` is useful for someone reading that who's not in front of Vim right now...) Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden, `gj` and `gk` are already mentioned in a comment below OP question. This answer is to specific question on how to use `k` and `j` to navigate those lines. If you feel it is incorrect and the right way to navigate is to use `gj` and `gk` then I don't mind if you edit the answer.

Comment: I mean, I am not that expert to tell ppl this is right vim way and this is overkill and shouldn't be used :)

Comment: Of course it's alright to suggest the mappings, but I think mentioning the normal commands first is best since they might be enough in many cases (as in, I know I'm in a long line, I'll use the alternate command here.) The mappings have side effects, so I think that should be addressed too. I edited the answer, I hope that's OK. If you disagree please revert (or further edit it to clarify.)

Comment: @filbranden thx for the edit -- it looks really good!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt from my `~/.vimrc`, which uses `gk` and `gj` commands to handle navigation through long lines:

```
nnoremap <Up>   gk
nnoremap <Down> gj
xnoremap <Up>   gk
xnoremap <Down> gj
inoremap <Up>   <C-O>gk
inoremap <Down> <C-O>gj
```

With these remaps in place, navigating through long lines using the arrow keys works just as expected in Normal (`nnoremap`), Visual (`xnoremap`) and Insert (`inoremap`) modes.  See also `:h i_CTRL-O`.