# Moving up and down wrapped lines

Tags: navigation

I have a text line (let's call it LINE) wrapped into some fifteen lines on the terminal screen (let's call these lines). Using only the keyboard I need to move up and down lines to edit. Keys j, k, up-arrow and down-arrow move to the neighbouring LINES (possibly some fifteen lines away!) which is not what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate long lines like separate lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22141/how-to-navigate-long-lines-like-separate-lines)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for -- thank you Luke. I almost gave up on vim because of this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can move up and down between the "display lines" of a wrapped line with the [`gj`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gj) and [`gk`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gk) normal mode commands.

If you find this unintuitive, a fairly common mapping is to swap these with the regular `j` and `k` commands:

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
nnoremap gj j
nnoremap gk k
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you Rich.