# Navigating wrapped paragraph as multiple lines

Tags: wrapping, navigation

Vim wraps text around as most other text editors, but does not allow the same kind of navigation within wrapped lines. Take for instance a piece of text composed of several long paragraphs. If the user hits the down key within a certain paragraph Vim hops down to the next paragraph. In an editor like GEdit the down key moves the cursor to the following wrapped line within the paragraph. This behaviour in Vim makes it rather cumbersome to edit text in the middle of an existing paragraph, it takes a while just to get the cursor to the right position.

How can Vim be instructed to navigated within paragraphs in the same way as GEdit? With the down and up keys moving the cursor within the paragraph and not hopping between paragraphs.

Comment: @MaximKim I went through that question and it seems to be asking for something else, related to the `$` wild card. And that question has no answers.

Comment: "How to navigate long lines like separate lines" the question is about the same thing. Wrapped lines and the way to navigate wrapped lines. `gj` and `gk`

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/88/1841